# Почему при делении получается бесконечность?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012

Заметил такое что у меня на локалке деление происходит без "бесконечности", а на Windows Server 2012 R2, почему-то получается "бесконечность".

```
dlouble lol = 100/(2500/90)/100;
```

Comment: Ну так обеспечьте выполнение вещественного деления, а не целого, и не будет ошибок.

Comment: А что такое `dlouble`?

Comment: @Akina, я думаю это double)

Comment: dlouble lol = 100.0/(2500/90)/100; :)

Comment: Выбор имен переменных у вас интересный

Comment: Ну а вообще, если вычисления  целые... сперва выполняется 2500/90=27 (ибо скобки), потом 100/27=3 (ибо слева направо), потом 3/100=0. Так что результат "бесконечность" - и правда странный.

Comment: То, что это код компилируется, уже достижение

Comment: Где-то мне встречалась идея про IDE с ачивками...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 
[Visual Studio Achievements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2012/02/28/visual-studio-achievements/) :)